# Create a 5x5 km polygon grid by sub-setting a 10x10km one

Tags: arcgis-desktop, vector-grid

I have a 10x10km grid in Lambert Conformal Conical projection (consider it as a sample frame).

I want to create another grid 5x5km by splitting in 4 parts each one of the original grid cells (the idea is to decrease the sample unit size maintaining a certain degree of spatial comparability).

In ArcGIS I tried creating a 5x5km polygon fishnet using as template the original grid. However, probably due to the conical projection, the output has got a variable shift from the input.

I then found a "Custom Grid Tool" (please see for reference http://ianbroad.com/creating-quarter-quarter-section-grid-python/)
which creates a polyline to be used to split the original grid into its quarter section. Unfortunately the original grid has too many polygons and the splitting operation makes the pc to crash.

How can we do this using ArcGIS Desktop?

Comment: Maybe convert your polygon grid to a point grid. Each point is an intersection of the grid. So with points' coordinates, generate new points that coordinates are at half-way... It's an idea, a way of research...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We made it. Once created the "shifted grid polyline"(with the "Custom Grid Tool", see above) we converted the original grid into polyline. Then we merged to 1 polyline grid 5x5km. Finally with "Feature to Polygon" we got the required output without having ArcGIS crashing...